# I have a multisite wordpress that's very volatile

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to migrate sites one by one-off that multi-site plugins will crash the whole multisite there no myphpadmin, I only have access to cmd line and FTP  how would I migrate the whole site and user, etc any recommendation without having to recreate the site.

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `to maximise your chance of getting an answer`, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Be sure to **[Be on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. `Update your question` with just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Comment: `Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based` may be **[closed by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)** until they are improved.

Answer (score 0):

All in One WP Migration with the Multisite extension.